# Trouble installing passenger gem on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger

From terminal

```
$ sudo gem install passenger
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
make
Makefile:104: *** missing separator.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread/gem_make.out
```

Don't understand this error, and why does it appear twice?  Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passenger 3.0.19 (the default version you get with `gem install`) is not ready for ruby 2. Either use ruby 1.9.3, or use the current passenger 4 beta.

Answer (score 3):

The command for installing the passenger 4 beta is `gem install passenger -v 4.0.0.rc4` which solved this error for me.

Comment: as of my comment the current version is rc6, gem install passenger -v 4.0.0.rc6 works good with ruby 2 from homebrew